# Notice: register_uninstall_hook was called incorrectly

Tags: wordpress, debugging

I automatically updated my wordpress installation to the latest version. Everything looked normal unit "updating database..." where it got stuck. I waited for a long while and then closed the page, since nothing was happening.

Then I got a error message saying something about maintenance, which I got rid of after deleting the maintenance file.

Wordpress displays that it runs the latest version, but when I try to reinstall I get the same errror. I've tried disabling all plugins and switch to the default theme, but no luck.

I set the debug to true and I got this message:
Notice: register_uninstall_hook was called incorrectly. Only a static class method or function can be used in an uninstall hook. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information.

Everything looks normal except a image on the front page is breaking the layout.
Any tips?

Comment: can you share your theme name or the plugins you're using

Answer (score 11):

The way I fixed this type of problem, was to do a global search in my project for the function call.

Some plugins had been installed which had calls such as this:

```
register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__, array($this,'uninstall_removedata'));
```

but it should be this:

```
register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, 'uninstall_removedata');
```

If you see a message that something is called incorrectly, the Codex can be very helpful to make sure you use the correct syntax.

In this case it is here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook

Comment: glad it could help, and on 12/12/12 no less!

Comment: The reason I believe is that the first example assumes the uninstall function is a method on a class instance. But per the rules of the hook, the uninstall method must be static, meaning independent of any class instance. Which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Some WordPress Plugin which you have installed is firing the uninstall hook and is not setup properly.

Can you find the path to the file from the error message?

Comment: I've disabled all plugins. I believe the path is wp-include/functions.php