# Wordpress plugin SEO Facebook causing error: Exception thrown without a stack fram

Tags: php, wordpress

When I active the plugin: SEO Facebook Comments in the place of page comments I get error:

> Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0

Then when I enable WP_DEBUG I get:

```
( ! ) Notice: register_uninstall_hook was called incorrectly. Only a static class method or function can be used in an uninstall hook. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.) in C:\wamp\www\wp-includes\functions.php on line 2944
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  365640  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0008  369280  require( 'C:\wamp\www\wp-blog-header.php' ) ..\index.php:17
3   0.0013  389656  require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\wp-load.php' )   ..\wp-blog-header.php:12
4   0.0019  405168  require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\wp-config.php' ) ..\wp-load.php:29
5   0.0028  508984  require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\wp-settings.php' )   ..\wp-config.php:92
6   0.2159  24384776    include_once( 'C:\wamp\www\wp-content\plugins\seo-facebook-comments\seofacebook.php' )  ..\wp-settings.php:195
7   0.2205  24806704    SEOFacebookComments->__construct( ) ..\seofacebook.php:594
8   0.2213  24816992    register_uninstall_hook( )  ..\seofacebook.php:95
9   0.2213  24817224    _doing_it_wrong( )  ..\plugin.php:679
10  0.2213  24818200    trigger_error ( )   ..\functions.php:2944
```

When I check [wp-content\plugins\seo-facebook-comments\seofacebook.ph](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/seo-facebook-comments/trunk/seofacebook.php)p line 195:
`wp_register_style('fbSEOStylesheet', $fbSEOStyleURL);`

Any ideas what is wrong with this or where I can start debugging this to find the error?

Using the latest version of WordPress.

UPDATE:
When I search the plugin directory I find 1 instance of register_untilstall_hook

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( &$this, 'install' ) );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( &$this, 'remove' ) );
register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, array( &$this, 'remove' ) );
```

UPDATE 2:
I was able to fix the error following this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11976433/560287 but I still get the original error in the comments section. Any ideas on what this could be?

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer, but you might want to try the Disqus plugin, which includes facebook integration. Unfortunately social media APIs are always changing, and typically things like this require a lot of maintenance.